# makefile automatic variable for corresponding c file

Tags: makefile

i hava a makefile something like this:

```
 outdir = release
 allsrc = aaa/a.c bbb/b.c ccc/c.c
allobjs = $(addprefix $(outdir), $(notdir $(allsrc:.c=.o))
...
test: $(allobjs)

$(allobjs): $(allsrc)
        gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

make test performs:

```
gcc -c -o release/a.o aaa/a.c
gcc -c -o release/b.o aaa/a.c
gcc -c -o release/c.o aaa/a.c
```

(automatic variable $< always takes first prerequisite)
but i want "corresponding one":

```
gcc -c -o release/a.o aaa/a.c
gcc -c -o release/b.o bbb/b.c
gcc -c -o release/c.o ccc/c.c
```

what should i change to accomplish desirable result?

i know that this will work for sure:

```
$(outdir)/a.o: aaa/a.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $<

$(outdir)/b.o: bbb/b.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $<

$(outdir)/c.o: ccc/c.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

and wondering how to accomplish the same in one receipe. (because in my real makefile i have ~20 different source files not just 3 like i made here for example)

Comment: If you won't pay attention to the sound advice in Etan's answer, you can experiment with `$*.c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do what you are asking would be something like:

```
outdir = release
allsrc = aaa/a.c bbb/b.c ccc/c.c
allobjs = $(addprefix $(outdir), $(notdir $(allsrc:.c=.o)))
VPATH = $(sort $(dir $(allsrc)))
...
test: $(allobjs)

$(outdir)/%.o: %.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

Of course, this will run into problems if you have a `b.c` in both `aaa` and `bbb`, but since you're trying to put all the object files in the same directory, you have that regardless.  It might make more sense to get rid of the `$(notdir` and keep the same directory structure under `$(outdir)`, in which case you don't need the `VPATH`

```
outdir = release
allsrc = aaa/a.c bbb/b.c ccc/c.c
allobjs = $(addprefix $(outdir), $(allsrc:.c=.o))
...
test: $(allobjs)

$(outdir)/%.o: %.c
        mkdir -p `dirname $@`
        gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't write your recipe like that. That's not how make works.

That recipe says that every item in `$(allobjs)` has **every** item in `$(allsrc)` as its prerequisite but that's not what you mean.

You mean that every `.o` file has the matching `.c` file as its prerequisite which is **exactly** what the built in `%.o: %.c` rule already does. You don't even need a makefile to do that.

Edit: Actually, you don't mean that. I had missed that the source files were in *different* directories. That changes and complicates things.

Chris Dodd [wrote up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36611818/258523) two good solutions for this.

Comment: well can you write me minimal example how to build aaa/a.c, bbb/b.c, and ccc/c.c to release/a.o, release/b.o, release/c.o, because that is what i am asking with this question